# Is there an alternative to .join() that works in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to use input from a Google Form (shown on the response spreadsheet) on a template Google Doc to generate a report.

I am using the code below to loop through all the answers and summarize certain answers in a list. (For example, if the user answered Daily, the text of that question will show in the list.)

However, by default, the results generated are all in one line separated by a comma. I'd like to use the .join() function to change the delimiter from a comma to a line break.

Google keeps returning this error:

TypeError: Cannot find function join in object Wipe down kitchen counters.
    at onFormSubmit(Code:41)

(Object "Wipe down kitchen counters" refers to one of the question's text, shown in the heading of the spreadsheet.)

I've read that join is a core Javascript function, not Google Apps Script. So, is there something wrong with my code? (I'm a beginner). OR does this function not work in Apps Script? and if so is there another function that would work?

Huge thanks for any help!!!

I've tried using the join function with other easy symbols, (% or *) instead of the line break in case that was the issue - but it returns the same error.

```
for (var key in e.namedValues) {
  if (e.namedValues[key][0] === 'Daily') 
dailyItems.push(key.replace('[','').replace(']','').trim().join("\n"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Show a sample of the object: `e.namedValues` and the expected output you're trying to get from that. FYI, there's no `join()` method in type `string`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your title question: [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) works fine in Apps Script, and you could convince yourself by looking at the editor Logs after running

```js
function verifyJoin() {
  Logger.log(["a","b","c"].join("\n"))
}
```

Try modifying your code like this:

```js
for (var key in e.namedValues) {
  if (e.namedValues[key][0] === 'Daily') {
    dailyItems.push(e.namedValues[key].join("\n"));
  }
}
```